# PHP URL encoding method

Tags: php, urlencode

How can I have PHP display this URL correctly?

Is there a working encoding method I can use that converts all of

```
253A%252F%252F
```

to

```
://
```

in

```
https%253A%252F%252Fvideos-private.s3.amazonaws.com%252Flesson05.flv
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[urldecode](http://fr.php.net/urldecode) ;)

Comment: I was expecting this to work but it doesn't. Please advise! Thank you.

$output = "file=https%253A%252F%252Fbassrx-private.s3.amazonaws.com%252Flesson05.flv"
$flv = urlencode ($output);
echo urlencode ($flv);

Answer (score 6):

You should use double urldecode, i.e.,

```
$beuty_url = urldecode(urldecode("https%253A%252F%252Fbassrxprivate.s3.amazonaws.com%252Flesson05.flv"));
echo $beuty_url;
```

Comment: Why double 'urldecode'? It sounds counterintuitive. It also seems to contradict the other answers. What is the explanation?

Answer (score 0):

The urldecode function decodes any %##  encoding in the given string.
In your "output" string you have %253A and so on.
Remove those %25 and everything will be fine.